# PixiJs cannot load image by loader

Tags: vue.js, pixi.js

I'm a beginner on PixiJs.
I want show a sprite image as some example, but I'm defeated.
The framework is Vue with Typescript.
I used `vue-cli` to generate a project ,and only modified the `App.vue` file like this:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <!-- <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App"/> -->
  <div ref='iv'></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
// import logo from '@/assets/logo.png';
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'


@Options({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
})
export default class App extends Vue {
  refs():any{
    return this.$refs
  }

  app=new PIXI.Application({width:400,height:300})

  setup(loader:PIXI.Loader){
      const bunny = new PIXI.Sprite(loader.resources.logo.texture);

      this.app.stage.addChild(bunny);
  }

  mounted(){
    this.refs().iv.appendChild(this.app.view)

    this.app.loader.add("logo","@/assets/logo.png").load(this.setup)
    
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

but if I use `import` to load image, like:

```
import logo from '@/assets/logo.png';
...
mounted(){
...
  let s=PIXI.Sprite.from(logo)
  this.app.stage.addChild(s)
...
}
```

It works.
What's my mistake?
How can I use the loader correctly?

Comment: First look here: https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Loader.html - there is written: `Adds a resource (or multiple resources) to the loader queue. This function can take a wide variety of different parameters. The only thing that is always required the url to load` and then there are example. As you see it needs to be url - so for example: "http: //mydomain.com/logo.png" (or https - depends). Also maybe you can try relative url: `/logo.png` . Also `setup` method (so callback in `loader.load`) accepts 2 parmas: `loader` and `resources`. Use those `resources` instead of `loader.resources`

Comment: Also try to put `console.log(resources)` in `setup` mehod and check if they have somthing in `error` field - because as you see in that doc: `error: The error that happened when trying to load (if any)` - so this may give some info.